# How to pass data from a web page to another web page in a different project (JSF 1.1 - ADF 10.1.3)

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

I've got two pages in two different projects (it means in different ear files that are deployed singularly) and i need to pass data from a page to another.

in the action of a command link i do

```
public String onSalva() {
     ADFContext.getCurrent().getApplicationScope().put("comingFrom", md);

     return "goToPrint";
}
```

and in the constructor method of the backing bean of the other page i do:

```
page = (String)ADFContext.getCurrent().getApplicationScope().get("comingFrom");
```

But page is always null. I tried using process, session and request scop with no luck. Is there a way i could redirect to the other page by specifying manually the parametrs?
Something like

```
   return "goToPrint?pageFrom="+md;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "different EAR", then that means the two applications are isolated from each other and there is no simple way to get data from one to the other via Java.

Instead, you have to use the HTTP protocol. If you just want to go to a URL, use [`HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)

This will open the new page in the browser as if the user had typed the URL into the location bar. *The browser will no longer talk to your first application*

If you want to stay in your first application and just send some data to the other side, there are several ways: You could embed the other app with an `iframe` - That would not allow you to exchange data but the user could fill and submit a form, for example.

Or you could use a library like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to talk to the other application. This would  allow you send POST requests and do everything a web browser could do with the other app.

Lastly, you could define a shared enterprise bean which both EARs consume. One approach would be to define a message service to which boths apps subscribe. The first one creates the messages and puts them into the queue and the second one waits for the message and does something with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's something i expected. I ended up playing with the URL!